# "ld: library not found for -lPods-VCOnCall-Bolts" Error for iOS 9.2 with Generic iOS Device Only

Tags: ios, parse-platform, bolts-framework

ld: library not found for -lPods-VCOnCall-Bolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I only received this error using "Generic iOS Device", there is no error using simulator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually link to libPods.a in Build phases "Link Binary With Libraries" for each additional target I had. Looks like after upgrading to iOS 9.2, the links got lost.

Hope this will help you.